# Why focus() method is not working?

Tags: javascript, magento-1.8

**Same code is worked on register.phtml page for focus() but this code is not working on personal.phtml.**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#rut").blur(function(){
            document.getElementById('error12').innerHTML ="";
            var Rut = $("#rut").val();
            var RemoveDotInRut = Rut.split('.').join("");
            var RemoveHypenInRut = RemoveDotInRut.split('-').join("");
            var freshString = RemoveHypenInRut.length;
            if(freshString<8 || freshString>9){
                document.getElementById('error12').innerHTML = "<?php echo $this->__('Please enter a valid Rut number.') ?>";
                $("#rut").val('');
                $("#rut").focus();
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

**Everything is worked in above script but focus() is not working. why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ys4go2n7/7/)

move your `.focus()` to there:

```
$(this).delay(0).queue(function() {
   $(this).focus().val("").dequeue();;
});
```

Also, i have optimized your codes. `$("#rut")` has replaced to `$(this)`

Comment: @AmitKushwaha. you're welcome. Also, you can do it with `setTimeout` (which @Jaromanda X said it). http://jsfiddle.net/ys4go2n7/8/

Comment: Oh Sorry, I did not get that. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

focus will be lost once the blur function ends, so setting focus inside the blur function has no effect

replace

```
    $("#rut").focus();
```

with

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#rut").focus();
}, 0);
```

which will "re-focus" the element in the next event loop

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, Can you tell me this function have to call in my script?

Comment: I'd say about 3:30PM if you hurry

Answer (score -2):

Use below code:

```
$("#focusedDiv").focus(function () {
    ....
});
```

Comment: how will assigning a focus event listener help?

Answer (score -2):

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focus.asp)!

Try out here from the basic.

Comment: this is no answer, and w3schools is not very well regarded around here